# Example of a working codebase with zoomable d3 circle packing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was exploring the zoomable circle packing library from d3:

https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-circle-packing

But I cannot for the love of god understand how it works. So I figured I would tinker with it by copying the code into an html file and then experimenting. Unfortunately copy the javascript here into a script tag (while referencing d3) was not sufficient to see a working chart.

To that end I did some more research and found that the package creator had a sample index.html in this post:

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/7607535

I replicated this index.html locally and ran it, which surprisingly worked, but then got the following error: my page doesn't render correctly.

See below image:
[image]

Compared to what was expected:

[image]

Code replicated here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = 20,
    diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 5])
    .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .padding(2);

d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/v1.1.8/test/data/flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
      view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

  svg
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      console.log(v);
      console.log(d.x);
      console.log(v[0]);
      return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")";
    });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following part of the code:

```
  root = d3.hierarchy(root)
  .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });
```

When calling `.sum`, the attribute `size` doesn't exists, so D3 is unable to calculate the circle radius, replace it by `value` and it will work.

Comment: how to add multilevel hierarchy upto 10